# Sorting tree sets without removing duplicates

Tags: java, lambda, comparator, treeset, sortedset

```
myData{
itemId,
location,
ExpDtTm,
userId
}
```

I trying to sort a TreeSet like so:

```
 TreeSet<myData> sorted = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(myData -> myData.ExpDtTm));
```

But there is a problem if any of the dates are equivalent they wont be added to the  tree set which proves to be a problem. If anyone knows what to do help is much appreciated.

I also tried

```
TreeSet<myData> sorted = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(myData -> myData.ExpDtTm).thencomparing(myData -> myData.itemId));
```

But it stopped excepting myData in both of the lambdas.

Comment: Then you need to consider it (add few more fields that determine the equality) in your comparator

Comment: If you just need you data (with duplicates) sorted, consider using a `List` and sort that.

Comment: Why do you use a TreeSet rather than a List, if you want duplicates?

Comment: @JBNizet The project that populates the set I get these values from returns a set and I don't have the access to change this. I just trying to work with what I'm given.

Comment: Not sure I understand: you get a Set from some project. What prevents you from putting all the values of the set inside a list and to sort the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
final SortedSet<myData> sorted = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<myData>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(myData o1, myData o2) {
                 int comparedValue = o1.expDtTm.compareTo(o2.expDtTm);
                 if(comparedValue == 0){
                       comparedValue = 1;
                 }
            }
});
```

Inside of that comparedValue `if` statement you can add any other variables you might want to sort with as well.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this happens is because the comparator is used to not only to determine the order but also to determine whether the two objects are equal (instead of `hashCode`, which a `HashSet` would use):

> a TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons using its
>   `compareTo` (or `compare`) method, so two elements that are deemed equal
>   by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal.

If you have two objects that aren't, in fact, identical but just happen to have the same date, you could use the object's [identity hash code](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode-java.lang.Object-) (effectively, it's memory address) as a secondary sorting condition:

```
TreeSet<myData> sorted = 
    new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(myData -> myData.ExpDtTm)
                            .thenComparingInt(System::identityHashCode));
```

Comment: Wait... why not `Object::hashCode`, which might be the identity hashcode, but might not be?

Comment: Feel free to edit what I've added. I didn't think it was worth adding a 3rd answer, and yours was the best so far.

Comment: @Michael two non-equal objects can have the same `hashCode()`, so I felt that `System.identityHashCode()` was safer.

Comment: If you compare on hashcode/identity hashcode, how does this provide any sorting on the object's `ExpDtTm` field? Why not use a `HashMap`? Same unordered result.

Comment: @M.leRutte the sorting is done first by `ExpDtTm`, and then, only for equal `ExpDtTm`s, ties are broken according to the identity hash code.

Comment: A HashSet doesn't use hashCode() to determine if two objects are equal. It uses equals(). hashCode is only used to reduce the number of potentially equal objects (i.e. choose the bucket).

Comment: Why can't I just create a new comparator??

Comment: @Mureinik two non-equal objects can have the same identity hash code as well. Any hash code is by definition vulnerable to collisions

Answer (score 2):

**Employee.Java**

```
private String name;

public Employee(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public String toString() {
    return "Employee[ id=" + name + "]";
}
```

Driver Class

**TreeSetTest.Java**

```
    TreeSet<Employee> treeSet = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<Employee>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Employee o1, Employee o2) {
            int index = o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
            return index==0?1:index;
        }
    });
    treeSet.add(new Employee("Harvansh"));
    treeSet.add(new Employee("Harvansh1"));
    treeSet.add(new Employee("Harvansh"));
    treeSet.add(new Employee("Harvansh2"));
    treeSet.add(new Employee("Harvansh"));
    treeSet.add(new Employee("Harvansh3"));
    treeSet.add(new Employee("Harvansh"));
    treeSet.forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Output**

Employee[ id=Harvansh]

Employee[ id=Harvansh]

Employee[ id=Harvansh]

Employee[ id=Harvansh]

Employee[ id=Harvansh1]

Employee[ id=Harvansh2]

Employee[ id=Harvansh3]

[Here Is The Complete Solution With Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQb5d.png)

Answer (score 1):

A `TreeSet` is an implementation of [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Set.html), which explicitly forbids duplicate entries by design. If you want a sorted collection that includes duplicates, use an implementation of `List` (e.g. `ArrayList`), and sort it at the end by calling [`Collections.sort(myList, Comparator.comparing(myData -> myData.ExpDtTm));`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-).

Comment: Sorry I changed the question a little but It doesn't have duplicates of the key I just want to sort by the Expiration.

Comment: @TOTOROCATBUS your comparator defines that two keys are equal if they have the same expiry date. The comparator doesn't just define the order. It also defines equality.

Comment: @TOTOROCATBUS I suggest you read the [documentation of `TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/TreeSet.html) carefully, and ensure you understand what you're working with.

Comment: Believe me I have read it along with LinkHashSet, HashSet, and SortedSet
I'm just trying to sort without removing duplicates and I have to use some kinda set so if you have any suggestions for a better set feel free.

Comment: @TOTOROCATBUS It's not at all clear why you "have to use some kinda set" -- do you need to pass it into something that accepts a `Set` after you've sorted it?

Comment: @DavidConrad Ok I'm sorry for my unclarity.  yes I have to pass the set to a ruby workflow which is only setup to handle sets.